# Better definitions of Reap and Sow

Tags: sow-reap

I am having tremendous difficulty understanding Reap and Sow in Mathematica. The definitions are pretty circular. When I look at the definition of Sow, I get, "specifies that e should be collected by the nearest enclosing **Reap**,specifies that e should be collected by the nearest enclosing **Reap** whose pattern matches tag, and specifies that e should be collected once for each pattern that matches a tag".  Then for reap, they do the same thing by using Sow in two of the definitions. I don't fully understand either. And the examples use tags in a way I don't really think of as tags in common English or real analysis. So, what are they actually talking about?

Answer (score 17):

Here a quick example how `Reap` and `Sow` are typically used:

```
Reap[
  Do[
   If[OddQ[i], Sow[i, "Odd"], Sow[i, "Even"]],
   {i, 1, 20}],
  _, Rule
  ][[2]]
```

> {"Odd" -> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19},   "Even" -> {2, 4, 6,
>   8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}}

Here `_` in `Reap` means that *arbitrary* tags should be collected by this particular `Reap`.

Other patterns than `_` are useful when we are dealing with nested instances of `Reap`. In the following, the inner `Reap` collects only tags of the form `"Odd"` while the outer collects `"Even"`:

```
b = Reap[
    a = Reap[
       Do[
        If[OddQ[i], Sow[i, "Odd"], Sow[i, "Even"]],
        {i, 1, 20}],
       "Odd", Rule
       ][[2]],
    "Even", Rule
    ][[2]];
a
b
```

> {"Odd" -> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}}
>
> {"Even" -> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}}

Replacing `Rule` with any other function, say `f` leads to

```
Reap[
  Do[
   If[OddQ[i], Sow[i, "Odd"], Sow[i, "Even"]],
   {i, 1, 20}],
  _, f
  ][[2]]
```

> {f["Odd", {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}],   f["Even", {2, 4, 6,
>   8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}]}

Comment: very helpful! Thanks for righting this.

Comment: @Henrik I am wondering if there is a more mathematical definition than what is given by Mathematica or through examples, like something using formal logic.

Comment: @Teg, I'm not sure why you need a "mathematical definition" here; `Sow[arg, tag]` is basically an instruction to "set aside" `arg`, and associate the tag `tag` with it, while `Reap[expr, tag]` is there to watch for and catch anything produced with the tag `tag` by any `Sow[]` inside, all while evaluating `expr`.